# React : new date() shows date of client machine rather than server

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react app running in a server with different locale where I am using

`new Date()`

When opening app from my client machine it returns the date of client locale instead of server locale , 
Reason ???

`let currDate = new Date();`

Comment: new Date() always return machine time.

Comment: Easiest solution is to only render dates client-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how javascript date works. Please refer to [MDN docs for `Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for more details. Also checkout the [the parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters) you can send to customize it.

> If no arguments are provided, the constructor creates a JavaScript Date object for the current date and time according to system settings for timezone offset
>
> Where Date is called as a constructor with more than one argument, the specified arguments represent local time
>
> The JavaScript Date object supports a number of UTC (universal) methods, as well as local time methods. UTC, also known as Greenwich Mean Time (GMT), refers to the time as set by the World Time Standard. The local time is the time known to the computer where JavaScript is executed.

Comment: Thanks , accepted the duplicate .